# What are the rules to use over correctly

Tags: prepositions

Are these prepositions alike: **above and over**

What is the difference in these sentence:

> - The bird flew over the tree.
> - The bird flew above the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As prepositions, *over* and *above* are very similar. There are only a few instances when one is preferred over the other. When quantifying, *over* is much better.

According to [English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/above-or-over?q=above%2Bover),

> We normally use *over* not *above* with numbers:
>
> I get over sixty emails a day.
>
> *Not: I get above sixty emails a day.*
>
> If you weigh over 100 kilograms, then you may need to start a diet.
>
> *Not: If you weigh above 100 kilograms*

- He is *over* six feet tall. (correct)
- He is *above* six feet tall. (wrong)

Or

- *Over* 50% of the population is tone deaf. (correct)
- *Above* 50% of the population is tone deaf. (wrong)

When used as an adverb, *over* also has the connotation of being to the side of something, instead of just on top of.

- I moved *over* to the left of the bureau.
- I moved *above* the bureau.

*Above* also has the connotation of being separate from something, which is not shared with *over*.

Consider `pour milk over your cereal` compared to `pour milk above your cereal`.

Comment: -1 Why is above six feet wrong? Above 50% of? "Moved over to" uses a different sense of *over*. Please cite your sources.

Comment: See http://www.gutenberg.org/files/31766/31766-h/31766-h.htm, rule #130

Comment: For something more modern, see https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/above-or-over?q=above%2Bover

Comment: As for "moved over to", it is clear that *over* implies lateral movement, while *above* implies vertical movement.

Comment: Include the references in the answer for the benefit of all readers. I did not find anything useful in what you've cited.